# Passing token Google Cloud Messaging between activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, token

I want to pass a token from one activity to another but I don't know what I can do because using Intent something is wrong.

With this activity I get the token:

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

// abbreviated tag name
static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";

public RegistrationIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Make a call to Instance API
    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    String senderId = getResources().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId);
    try {
        // request token that will be used by the server to send push notifications
        String token = instanceID.getToken(senderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
        Log.d(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
        // pass along this data
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

With this activity I pass the code inside my server:

```
  public void userLogin(View view){
    login_name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
    login_pass = ET_PASS.getText().toString();
    String method = "login";
    String token = getRegTokenId();
    BackgroundTaskLogin backgroundTask = new BackgroundTaskLogin(mContext);
    backgroundTask.execute(method, login_name, login_pass, token);
}



private void getRegTokenId(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have things a little confused.  Your `RegistrationIntentService` is actually a service not an activity, the code below that is probably contained in an activity.

It's a little hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do but my guess is that the `userLogin()` method is supposed to use some info from your activity to generate the GCM device token, and then log your user into some server and include the GCM device token as part of the info sent during the login.

You are assuming that `getRegTokenId()` will return you the GCM device token, but it does not , in fact it returns void, as defined in your code.

```
private void getRegTokenId(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

It looks like you are trying to follow a tutorial or something,  and in this case it looks like the idea is that the `RegistrationIntentService` is supposed to handle the part of logging into the service, or at least uploading the token.

```
public void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

So what I think you really want to do is rather than get the token in the activity, I think you want to get the rest of the login info into the service so that it is available to the `sendRegistrationToServer()`

You can add that info into the intent you send to `startService()`

```
private void getRegTokenId(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra("SOME_KEY","SOME_VALUE"); // add info to the intent
    startService(intent);
}
```

You can then get that back in the service using

```
someValue = getStringExtra("SOME_KEY");
```

If you really want to get the token back from the service, there are ways to do that also, you can read up on intent services [here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).